# 3D printed part sticking to the support layer

Tags: pla, support-structures, flashforge-creator

I am using a Flash Forge Creator, and when I print big parts (only in this case) I have about 25% of the bottom of the printed object sticking very hard to its support layer. And I spend a lot of time removing it with a cutter.

Is there any clue or good practice to avoid that?

I use ReplicatorG for my printing settings.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found out two causes:

1. The 3D printer has default settings for ABS, and since there is no printer bed settings in ReplicatorG, the bed temperature was set to 110 °C instead of  60°C. I fixed the setting directly on the printer itself.
2. It seems that one side of the printer bed was little closer to the nozzle than other sides (relatively to the extruder) and this added a pressure on the support layer. I found this by observing the structure of the support layer that was little more compressed in one side. That was easy to fix by iteratively tightening/loosening the screw of that side and observing the support layer (and canceling the print if it is not homogeneous).

I installed Ultimaker Cura and Slic3r to try them and I found that Ultimaker Cura was not adapted to my printer (I did not found a complying model), Slic3r seems to be okay but I was not able to fit my big part inside of it.
I am trying to use the maximum available space for my part, perhaps I need to change some settings for Slic3r and anyway it is already working on ReplicatorG.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer! Actual solutions of the OP's are always welcome! Just for your information, do note that your printer does not have to be in that list to actually use other software. Mainly basic settings are needed to make the configuration work for your printer; e.g. bed size and G-code flavor, these are easily found and inserted. Please accept your answer after 48 hours! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to the manufacturer:

> ... you are able to choose your favorite software such as
>   FlashPrint, Simplify3D, Cura and more.

Not being familiar with ReplicatorG, I know that other slicer software can set the distance between supports and print (in terms of the amount of layers). You could look for such a setting in ReplicatorG, or use a different slicer such as Ultimaker Cura or Slic3r; which are free and able to make such adjustments.